# Serverless yml assigning an S3 'array' variable instead of multiple config values

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I have a plugin in serverless that I'm using that has a config value that requires multiple entries (see below):

```
-name: 'test'
  samples:
    - string example one
    - string example two
    - etc etc etc
```

Instead of defining each sample entry, I want to be able to read from somewhere externally so I can automate the appending of new values. I know you can define S3 variables, but is there any way to supply the samples config value with some array data in S3? So it might look something like:

```
-name: 'test
  samples: ${path-to-array-or-s3-bucket}
```

Array:

```
['string example one', 'string example two', 'etc etc etc']
```

Or alternatively, a way to append values to serverless.yml in node.js based on the name key?